# How to cancel event in a function

Tags: python

I need to cancel a specific event in which the user input the name. However  `s.cancel` never allows me to do that since I'm guessing the variable is local. What can I do?

Here is my code:

```
import sched
import time

s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)

def print_job_name(msg):
    print(msg)

def alarm(name):
    name = s.enter(5,1,print_job_name,("Hey",))
    print(type(name))
    return name

alarm('hey')
alarm('Good Morning')
alarm('hello')
s.cancel(hey)
s.run()
```

Comment: Make use of the event object you return so you can call cancel on it, eg: `hey = alarm('hey')`... then you can do `s.cancel(hey)`...

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean... could you give some sample code?

Comment: I already did in the above comment... you just store the return value instead of ignoring it...

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain myself well enough in the post. The issue is that I eventually I will need the input of that function to store the event, I'm working on a project where the user will be able to cancel alarms. However I'm guessing there is no way of calling that back again outside of the function.

Comment: Sounds like you should store a dictionary of "some key to identify event": event_object and use that

Answer (score 0):

```
import sched
import time

s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
scheduled_events = {}
def print_job_name(msg):
    print(msg)


def alarm(name):
    name = s.enter(5,1,print_job_name,("Hey",))
    print(type(name))
    return name

scheduled_events['hey'] = alarm('hey')
scheduled_events['Good Morning'] = alarm('Good Morning')
scheduled_events['hello'] = alarm('hello')
s.cancel(scheduled_events['hey'])
s.run()
```

This is not the best method of storing your events as your args can be the same for 2 different events. However, this should get you started.